# Vaadin Valo Demo Menu in application header

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

How to tell Vaadin Menu from [Valo Demo Application](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common) to always be sticky to application header ?

I need my application menu to be in the following state:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9VG1.png)

Comment: Do youeam that the menu bar should always be visible, no matter where the user scrolls down?

Comment: Yes, but should only be visible in the header of the application and not as a left panel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with a following styles:

```
@mixin valo-menu-responsive() { 
  .v-ui {

    @include width-range() {
      padding-top: $v-unit-size;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;

      .v-loading-indicator {
        top: $v-unit-size;
      }

      > .v-widget {
        position: relative !important
      }

      .valo-menu {
        border-right: none;
      }

      .valo-menu-part {
        overflow: visible;
      }

      .valo-menu-toggle {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .valo-menu-title {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: $v-unit-size !important;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      }

      .valo-menu .v-menubar-user-menu {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: $v-unit-size;
        color: valo-font-color($v-selection-color, 0.5);
        max-width: 30%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

        .v-menubar-menuitem {
          line-height: $v-unit-size - 1px;
          white-space: nowrap;
        }

        img.v-icon {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 0 round($v-unit-size / 6) 0 0;
          width: round($v-unit-size / 2);
          height: round($v-unit-size / 2);
          border-radius: ceil($v-unit-size / 4);
          border: none;
        }
      }

      .valo-menuitems {
        @include valo-menu-style;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 200;
        top: $v-unit-size;
        bottom: 0;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: round($v-unit-size / 2) 0;
        @include transform(translatex(-100%));
        @include transition(all 300ms);
      }

      .valo-menu-visible .valo-menuitems {
        @include transform(translatex(0%));
      }
    }

    @include width-range($max: 500px) {
      .valo-menu-toggle .v-button-caption {
        display: none;
      }

      .valo-menu .v-menubar-user-menu .v-menubar-menuitem-caption {
        display: inline-block;
        width: round($v-unit-size / 2);
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    }
  }
 }
```